# If, elsif, else behavoir

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby and have simple If, Elsif, Else statements. The else is always run. I have read several examples and do not see what I did wrong.

```
if ip_voice.any?{ |o| @filter =~ /\b#{Regexp.escape(o)}\b/ }
      @catagory = "ip_voice"
elsif ip_pbx.any?{ |o| @filter =~ /\b#{Regexp.escape(o)}\b/ }
      @catagory = "ip_pbx"
elsif ip_video_surveillance.any?{ |o| @filter =~ /\b#{Regexp.escape(o)}\b/ }
      @catagory = "ip_video_surveillance"
elsif ip_video_telephony.any?{ |o| @filter =~ /\b#{Regexp.escape(o)}\b/ }
      @catagory = "ip_video_telephony"
elsif enterprise_gateways.any?{ |o| @filter =~ /\b#{Regexp.escape(o)}\b/ }
      @catagory = "enterprise_gateways"
else consumer_atas.any?{ |o| @filter =~ /\b#{Regexp.escape(o)}\b/ }
      @catagory = "consumer_atas"
        ...run code...
end
```

I have moved the statments in different orders and the code always runs well, just always the else statement. Am I missing something? Thank you

Comment: What is in `@filter`? Does it match one of the regexp in `ip_voice`, `ip_pbx`, etc?

Comment: @CMoi The filter matches and sets the catagory. The filters are good, when I moved the statements in different orders the filters catch the correct ones.

Comment: @raina77ow The filter will always match. I just want it to set the catagory variable according to the filter.

Comment: why are you passing an argument to `else`???

Comment: when you have this many `if/elsif/else` block you need to rethink a `case` switch would be more readable/ideal

Comment: @bjhaid I do not understand why a case statement would be more ideal. I personally can read if/elsif/else statements easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's exactly zero sense attaching any condition to `else` branch - this branch is executed only if checks for all the other branches (clauses given in `if` and `elsif` parts ) fail.

That's why Ruby treats your code as follows:

```
else 
  consumer_atas.any?{ |o| @filter =~ /\b#{Regexp.escape(o)}\b/ }
@catagory = "consumer_atas"
```

... i.e., always setting the `@catagory` variable with value specified in `else`.